# Ansible 'get_url' error - URL can't contain control characters

Tags: jenkins, ansible, wget

Getting error in Ansible `get_url` module:

> URL can't contain control characters`.

Sample code:

```yaml
- get_url:
    url: "{{ jenkins_url_repo }}" --no-check-certificate
```

I've also tried the following, but the error still persist.

```yaml
url: "{{ jenkins_url_repo }} {{ no-check-cert }}"
url: https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.repo --no-check-certificate
url: "https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.repo --no-check-certificate"
url: 'https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.repo --no-check-certificate'
```

Answer (score 2):

`--no-check-certificate` looks like it's supposed to be part of some other command, not part of the URL.

Probably you've copied this from somewhere that is fetching the file and disabling checking of the remote SSL certificate, because of incorrectly configured local trusted roots.

You probably want to just leave it off and let the certificate be verified so that you don't install malicious software!

If you're really sure you want to ignore the security check, the Ansible equivalent is [the validate_certs option](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/get_url_module.html#parameter-validate_certs).

```yaml
- get_url:
    url: "{{ jenkins_url_repo }}" --no-check-certificate
    # WARNING! DISABLING SECURITY! THIS IS DANGEROUS!
    validate_certs: no
    # WARNING! DISABLING SECURITY! THIS IS DANGEROUS!
```